# Integral of elements of random unitaries

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, random-matrices, symmetric-groups

It is known how to calculate the integral of elements of $N\times N$ Haar random unitaries using the Weingarten function:
$$\int \prod_{k=1}^n U_{i_kj_k} U_{m_kr_k}^* \mathrm d U = \sum_{\sigma,\tau} \mathrm{Wg}^U(\tau^{-1}\sigma, N)\prod_{k=1}^n [i_k=m_{\sigma(k)}][j_k=r_{\tau(k)}]$$
where $\mathrm{Wg}^U$ is the Weingarten function.

I am looking to calculate
$$\int \prod_{k=1}^n |U_{i_kj_k}|^2 \mathrm d U$$
for $n=4$, and find it is already difficult to apply the above equation for such a simplified case. Is there a reference about special cases of the moments I can refer to without messing up the calculation myself?

Comment: for large $N$ you can take the elements as independent Gaussians, and the integral will tend to $N^{-n}$; closed form expressions for any $N$ are not available.

Comment: If you want to go beyond the formal expression, you must have some information about the sequences $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$. Are all indices equal? Are they all different? etc.